# symfony php framework - preg_replace_callback Requires argument 2, to be a valid callback

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having this error while I'm trying to install symfony on WAMPserver.

```
Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2, 'str_replace(' ', 
'=PLACEHOLDER=', '//2')', to be a valid callback in 
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9\pear\symfony\command\sfCommandManager.class.php 
on line 111
```

Where the line of code is the following one:

```
111 $arguments = preg_replace_callback('/(\'|")(.+?)\\1/e', "str_replace(' ', 
'=PLACEHOLDER=', '//2')", $arguments);
112 $arguments = preg_split('/\s+/', $arguments);
113 $arguments = str_replace('=PLACEHOLDER=', ' ', $arguments);
```

Did someone encounter this same problem while they were installing symfony?
How did you fix it?

Comment: You seem to be trying to install Symfony 1.. the world is currentlv at Symfony 3 (4 in November). How did you install this? If you are working on an old project then you are stuck on old tech. If you are working on a new project then you are working on old information, so you should look at https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html instead.

Comment: I followed this guide to install it:
[link](https://jonpolygon.com/installing-symfony-wamp/#comment-14148)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you have been installing the old version of Symfony (1.4) which reach end of maintenance in November of 2012. if you follow the link I provided (https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) there are details for how to set up the latest version of Symfony (3.3 at present) on multiple systems, WAMP included. If you are actively trying to install version 1.X, however, then I'm afraid I can't help.